# Globalize Fallback does not work in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, globalize

I have the following I18n-Setup

```
config.i18n.available_locales = [:de, :en]
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = true
config.i18n.default_locale = :de
```

I have a URL-based locale-switch:

```
# routes.rb
scope '(:locale)/', locale: /en|de/, defaults: {locale: 'de'} do
  resources :programmes
  root 'programmes#portal'
end
```

In my ApplicationController I set the locale as a `before_filter`

```
# application_controller.rb  
before_filter :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale =  params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end
```

In my `application.rb`

```
config.i18n.available_locales = [:de, :en]
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = true
config.i18n.default_locale = :de
```

I have a fallback for both of my languages (`/app/initializers/globalize.rb`):

```
Globalize.fallbacks = {:en => [:en, :de], :de => [:de, :en]}
```

My `development.rb` and `production.rb` don't differ in terms of I18n setup.

Now I run into the following problem:

1. I have a record which is only tranlsated in `EN`
2. In my development environment using locale = `DE` the fallback to the english title works
3. However, in production environment this fallback does not work.

It is not clear to my why this does not work in production environment.

**Update**: In the production console on my production environment the fallback seems to work as well:

```
irb(main):005:0* I18n.locale
=> :de

irb(main):006:0> p=Programme.find(1289)
=> #<Programme id: 1289, created_at: "2014-07-08 09:58:21", ....>

irb(main):007:0> p.title
=> "English Title"

irb(main):008:0> I18n.locale = :en
=> :en

irb(main):009:0> p.title
=> "English Title"

irb(main):010:0> I18n.locale = :something-undefined
=> :something-undefined

irb(main):011:0> p.title    
=> nil

irb(main):012:0> I18n.default_locale
=> :de
```

Comment: I cross-posted this as a globalize issue: https://github.com/globalize/globalize/issues/362

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**

```
# config/application.rb
require 'i18n/backend/fallbacks'
```

**Answer**

I recently had a similar error in development environment.

Here it is my relevant code setup:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'globalize', '5.0.1'
gem 'rails', '4.2.2'
gem 'rails-i18n', '4.0.4'
```

and:

```
# config/application.rb
config.i18n.available_locales = [:it, :en]
config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = true
config.i18n.default_locale = :it
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
```

With this setup i got these results:

```
2.2.2 :001 > Product.find_by_name('Fun Farm').translations.inspect
 => "#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Product::Translation id: 16, product_id: 16, locale: \"it\", created_at: \"2015-06-20 08:33:51\", updated_at: \"2015-06-20 08:33:51\", awards: \"Vincitore della <strong>Ludoteca Ideale</strong>, ...\", spot: \"Il party game per chi ha i riflessi pronti.\", synopsis: \"<p>\\n  Gli animali stanno scappando dalla fattoria ...\">]>"
2.2.2 :002 > Product.find_by_name('Fun Farm').spot
 => "Il party game per chi ha i riflessi pronti." 
2.2.2 :003 > I18n::locale = :en
 => :en
2.2.2 :004 > Product.find_by_name('Fun Farm').spot
 => nil
```

Adding:

```
# config/application.rb
require 'i18n/backend/fallbacks'
```

it works:

```
2.2.2 :001 > Product.find_by_name('Fun Farm').translations.inspect
 => "#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Product::Translation id: 16, product_id: 16, locale: \"it\", created_at: \"2015-06-20 08:33:51\", updated_at: \"2015-06-20 08:33:51\", awards: \"Vincitore della <strong>Ludoteca Ideale</strong>, ...\", spot: \"Il party game per chi ha i riflessi pronti.\", synopsis: \"<p>\\n  Gli animali stanno scappando dalla fattoria ...\">]>"
2.2.2 :002 > Product.find_by_name('Fun Farm').spot
 => "Il party game per chi ha i riflessi pronti." 
2.2.2 :003 > I18n::locale = :en
 => :en
2.2.2 :004 > Product.find_by_name('Fun Farm').spot
 => "Il party game per chi ha i riflessi pronti."
```